# MVC Login form is not being redirected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Actually i have copied one of the system for MVC 3 from one project but now its seem like i am struggling to have this redirection problem

// POST: /Account/LogOn

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    **return Redirect(returnUrl);**
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

so when i use xxx.com/admin it takes me to login page and follow the above code but after successful username and password it should redirect to the admin home page which it is not.
Can anyone have any idea this that would be helpful for me to continue.

Cheers

Comment: does the `returnUrl` parameter have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
      {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
      }
      else
      {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", 
                            "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
  }
  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem all the time. You need to pass the returnUrl up to the form as a hidden input to be passed back on your Login POST.

```
public ActionResult LogOn(returnUrl) {
   return View(returnUrl);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel input) {
  return Redirect(input.ReturnUrl);
}
```

The issue is that you see the returnUrl in the browsers URL bar, but if you look at your FORM action it probably just goes to "/LogOn".

Your other option is to take the Url to the action of the log on form.

Hope that helps.